# Sticker bundle app - how to prepare it for submission

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I have a sticker bundle (not iMessage app) and when I go to the `Product` menu the `Archive` option is disabled. How is this bundle suppose to be made ready for being published?

The sticker bundle is not part of any app. It is independent (zero coding).

Can someone please tell me what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `Generic iOS Device` from the list of devices and option will become active. It doesn't make sense to create a release build for simulator.